# Crystal reports total with databse field that changes on each group

Tags: crystal-reports

Boas 
Pretendo copiar dentro da mesma crosstab o valor de 1 celula para outra
Como faço

Como fazer isto

Cumrpimentos

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta não está nem um pouco clara. Você pode clicar em [edit] a qualquer momento e adicionar mais informações para melhorar nosso entendimento do seu problema. Recomendo que faça o [tour], veja [ask] e [como criar um exemplo, mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve)

Comment: Pelo que entendo não faz pois cada item de uma "crosstab" é pontual , ligado à somente um campo ou fórmula, o Crystal permite que um campo seja inserido mais de uma vez , fazendo diferentes agregadores , soma e média por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Precisava ttambem de saber se da para colocar nas labels dos totalizadores um valor proveniente da bd.?

Comment: Isto não ficou claro.

Comment: Boa tarde

A crosstab a medida que vamos adicionado colunas adiciona te uma coluna de totalizador com a label "Total" e eu preciso que esta label "Total" apareça "Total" + "campo da base de dados"

Comment: ponto 1. tenho 1 crosstab
ponto 2: a crosstab tem varias linhas de total
ponto 3: esses totais tem uma label 
ponto 4:Eu quero editar essa label para em vez de ter TOTAL ter TOTAL E UM CAMPO DA BD